# Passing a user, request to forms

Tags: django, django-forms

How would I pass a user object or a request to my form for validation?

For example, I want to be able to do something like this --

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    ...
    def clean(self)
        user = request.user   # how to get request.user here?
        user = User           # how to pass the actual User object?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just pass it into the constructor and store it as an instance variable:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        print self.request.user
        ...
```

In your view:

```
form = MyForm(..., request=request)
```

And if using a class-based view (a CreateView in this example):

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):

    ... 

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs
```

Comment: strange but this doesnot work: NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Is this still working in django 2? I've followed everything but the the kwargs are not updated in the form..

Comment: Yes. It works in Django 2.0.2 Perhaps you need to pass `**kwargs` to the method `def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(MyCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()` And don't do `self.request` before call super. Just user `request = kwargs.pop("request")` Perhaps you could user `self.request` after calling super.

Comment: I also am having issues with this in 2.0