# forms.ModelForm Restrict to User Who Created the Model

Tags: python, django, forms

Simply asked: **In a form, how do you restrict the display of a many-to-many relationship to the records the user has defined himself?**

---

In an effort to keep things as DRY as possible, I'm using `forms.ModelForm`.

Here in Example, a user can create feed-items which run on a schedule. Technically the feeds and the items are connected to the user by `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`  however that in itself is not enough to restrict the association of the two through the user himself.

While I'd love to inherently restrict association of the two THROUGH the user, I'd be happy to simply restrict the display of the items via user and simply validate afterwards. Example data below:

---

```
class Example(models.Model):

    global CHOICES_DAYS
    global CHOICES_HOURS

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    label = models.CharField(max_length=180)    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)

    Example_feeds = models.ManyToManyField(ExampleFeed, blank=True)

    hourly_schedule = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_HOURS, max_length=2, default=4)
    weekly_schedule = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_DAYS, max_length=5, default=1)
    last_used = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=False)     

    def __str__(self):            
        return self.label

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('last_used',)
```

And here is the form, of which I'm using forms.ModelForm to keep things as DRY as possible:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = ''
        self.helper.form_class = ''
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta():
        model = Example
        fields = [
            'label', 
            'title', 
            'content', 
            'example_feeds', 
            'hourly_schedule', 
            'weekly_schedule']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [pass the `request.user` to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325681/passing-a-user-request-to-forms) when you are instantiating it in your view and then make use of that request object to [restrict the form field's `queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships).

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mym2mfield'].queryset = Example.objects.filter(example_feeds__user=request.user)
```

and in your view (assuming it's a class based view):

```
class MyView(FormView):
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        return form_class(self.request, self.get_form_kwargs())
```