# Django 2 request.POST not saving to database with instance=request.user

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a form where a user can submit some text, which then gets saved to the model `TextSubmission`.

However, it only saves when I take out `instance=request.user` from `views.py` and it does not save with the instance of the user who submitted it.

If I leave `instance=request.user` in, the `request.POST` object does not get saved but does get posted. (I can see from `print(request.POST)`

Can someone help me figure out why this is and how to get the text to save along with the user?

models.py

```
class TextSubmission(models.Model):
    text_submission    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    user                   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['text_submission']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text_submission
```

forms.py

```
class TextSubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TextSubmission
        fields = ['text_submission']
```

views.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        t_form = TextSubmissionForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if p_form.is_valid() and t_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            t_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        t_form = TextSubmissionForm(instance=request.user.textsubmission)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form,
        't_form': t_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

profile.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="profile-form">
          {{ p_form }}
          {{ t_form }}
   </div>
   <button type="submit" value="submit">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

Comment: instance must be an instance of the Model used by the form. You can’t pass a `User` instance to your `TextSubmissionForm` because instance needs to be a `TextSubmission`.

Comment: But what about when a new user profile is created and doesn't yet have an instance of a `TextSubmission` associated with it? That throws the `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`

Comment: That's why you should have `except TextSubmission.DoesNotExist: ...`, so the exception isn't thrown but handled. ie. you also need to do try .. except in your else block.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand why that is necessary now. The `request.POST` still doesn't save with the instance of the user though...it only saves the text.

Comment: For a new one you mean? That's because your form only has the field 'text_submission' so it doesn't associate a user to the text. Actually I would expect your code to crash because `user` is mandatory in your model. Normally, for this, you would do something like: `submission = t_form.save(commit=False); submission.user = request.user; submission.save()`. Or adapt your form as shown in the answer by @JPG to also pass the user, which is a better separation of concerns (the form saves the instance).

Comment: Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the TextSubmission form an instance of User, when you want to be passing it an instance of TextSubmission. Try

```
try:
    t_form = TextSubmissionForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.textsubmission)
except TextSubmission.DoesNotExist:
    t_form = TextSubmissionForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: When I do this I get `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no textsubmission.` I'm assuming this happens because `user` is a `OneToOneField` in `TextSubmission`

Comment: You need to first check if it exists and then depending on the result pass it or not. That will determine whether the form creates the object or updates the existing one. You can wrap the above call in a `try ... except`

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I don't get an error anymore however the user instance is still not saving with the `TextSubmission`, only the text

Comment: @dirkgroten I get `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
User has no textsubmission.` because the text object obviously doesn't exist yet on first loading of the page, but how come the `p_form` doesn't throw any errors (as it doesn't have any data yet?)

Comment: Just realised it's because I have a signal to create a profile every time a new user is made.

Comment: @Trilla where do you get `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`? if you do try except as shown, you're catching that. So it must be somewhere else you're trying to access `user.textsubmission`.

Comment: What should the `else` block be? I have it right now as `t_form = TextSubmissionForm(instance=request.user.textsubmission)` which is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Override the **`__init__()`** method and **`save()`** method of the form as

```
class TextSubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.user = self.user
        return super().save(commit)

    class Meta:
        model = TextSubmission
        fields = ['text_submission']
```

Then, in your views,

```
def profile_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST)  # change is here
        t_form = TextSubmissionForm(request.POST, user=request.user)  # change is here

        if u_form.is_valid() and t_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            t_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm()  # change is here
        t_form = TextSubmissionForm()  # change is here

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        't_form': t_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

---

#### Reference

1. [Passing a user, request to forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325681/passing-a-user-request-to-forms)

Comment: That would be correct if creating a new user, but I think the OP is updating existing records, so passing the `instance` to the model form is still required. Not sure about `TextSubmission` though, i'd expect that to be either update (if it already exists) or create.

Comment: Yes @dirkgroten at the moment the textsubmission is in a bit of a funny place, it's alongside update profile for now, but yes with the single `request.POST` I'm both updating existing records and also submitting new `textsubmissions`

Answer (score -1):

The instance require the instance of the referenced model in form definition. In your case it is `TextSubmission`, so you have first get object of this model and then pass it to the `TextSubmissionForm`

```
user = User.objects.get(id = request.user)
txtSubmsn = TextSubmission.objects.get(user)
u_form = TextSubmissionForm(instance=txtSubmsn)
```

Same case for `UserUpdateForm`

Comment: I don't understand why `UserUpdateForm` works fine though?