# Changing the contents of an input in a django form with request data in __init__()

Tags: python, django

I've got a django form which contains a TypedMultipleChoiceField containing a group of users. I got the users from the auth User model, but I want to remove the current logged in user form the choices. I've been trying to do this by bringing in the request data into the form's init method and then deleting the logged in user from the choices list, but for some reason the form still renders the logged in user in the list of choices. Code below:

Views.py

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView, generic.edit.FormMixin):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(IndexView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id).order_by('begin_date')

    form_class = CreateProject
    context_object_name = 'project_list'
    template_name = 'projects/project_index.html'
```

forms.py

```
class CreateProject(forms.Form):
    contributor_id = forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField(choices=list(User.objects.values_list('id','username')),
                                                    required=False, empty_value=[])
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user")
        super(CreateProject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = self.fields['contributor_id'].choices
        del choices[choices.index((self.user.id, self.user.username))]
```

When I put in a pdb.set_trace() into the init method and check the state of the form fields after performing the delete everything looks correct. What am I doing wrong?

For reference, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325681/passing-a-user-request-to-forms) for the get_form_kwargs in views and init in forms.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but why not use a `ModelMutipleChoiceField` where you change the queryset to remove the logged in user?

Comment: @dirkgroten Good point, I'm new to django so I din't know of its existence.. I've changed my code and now everything works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the TypedMultipleChoiceField to a ModelMultipleChoiceField and then set the queryset as the User group (bar the logged in user) in the init method:

views.py

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView, generic.edit.FormMixin):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(IndexView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user_id': self.request.user.id})
        return kwargs

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id).order_by('begin_date')

    template_name = 'projects/project_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'project_list'
    form_class = CreateProject
```

forms.py

```
class CreateProject(forms.Form):
    contributor_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop("user_id")
        super(CreateProject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contributor_id'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(id=self.user_id)
```

Comment: May I kindly suggest a couple enhancements ? First, if the only thing you need from the request is the current user id, don't pass the whole request to the form, only pass the current user id - it will make your form much easier to unittest. Also - this is really a minor thing but -, `ModelManager` (your model's `objects` attribute) directly exposes the underlying Queryset's `exclude` method (and quite a few other actually), so  `YourModel.objects.all().exclude(...)` is redundant - `YourModel.objects.exclude(...)` works just fine and avoids useless instanciations, copies and method calls.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the advice, I've made the changes in my code. Should I edit the question & answer too?